# Tip vs Hint (advice)

Tags: word-difference

If we are refering to advice on how to do something or archive something, a short message like in software when you hover your mouse over an item, is there a difference between **a tip** and **a hint**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference between the two terms is one of directness. A *hint* is indirect; when you're giving someone a hint you're usually trying to impart the smallest amount of information to lead them to an answer or conclusion. A *tip* is more direct; while the relative amount of information given is the same, it's usually **the** bit of missing information the other person needs.

In other words, a tip is an obvious small piece of helpful information. A hint is a not-as-obvious small piece.

Comment: Is this a difference between the two English words in general, or in the context of software and user interfaces?

Comment: @J.R. This is in general.